# CakePhp href links to different controller's view

Tags: cakephp, view, controller, href

I have 2 Controllers CubeController.php and CuboidController.php .
Both of them have there Indec.ctp as views.
I want to create a link to call the view of cuboidController on the view of the cubeController page?
How should I proceed????

Answer (score 1):

You can do this;

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link( "Here a message",   array('controller' => 'cube', 'action' => 'index') ); ?>
```

Comment: Its shows the following error:
Error: The action Cube is not defined in controller CuboidController

Error: Create CuboidController::Cube() in file: app/Controller/CuboidController.php.

Comment: Tried this to: @Widrogo
$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'cube', 'action' => 'index'));

Comment: the error is because you don't have a function "Cuboid" is other problem, redirect is not the same that a link, inside your question you put href and go to oter controller and view with a link.